# contour plot of a custom function in R

Tags: r, plot, contour

I'm working with some custom functions and I need to draw contours for them based on multiple values for the parameters.

Here is an example function:

[image]

I need to draw such a contour plot:

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have your values for x-axis and y-axis or just use the values as shown in figure?

Comment: This does look like homework.

Comment: Indeed. It's not clear what 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 stand for?

Comment: It doesn't matter what they stand for. The problem is well posed and I have a solution but  I'm still hesitant to just post an answer that seems to be doing someone's HW.

Comment: then this should be good candidate for closure

Comment: I left the section that I considered difficult unsolved. If this is not homework and solving that "example" function with R isn't really the task, then I think the answer is responsive. I don't think SO expects that all HW Q's should be closed, but rather there should be academic honesty and the student should show effort.

Comment: No, Be sure! This is not a HW. I tried a lot of codes without success, and as I said, this is just an example of many custom function that I'm working on them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First you construct a function, `fourvar` that takes those four parameters as arguments. In this case you could have done it with 3 variables one of which was lambda_2 over lambda_1. Alpha1 is fixed at 2 so alpha_1/alpha_2 will vary over 0-10.

```
fourvar <- function(a1,a2,l1,l2){ 
  a1* integrate( function(x) {(1-x)^(a1-1)*(1-x^(l2/l1) )^a2} , 0 , 1)$value }
```

The trick is to realize that the `integrate` function returns a list and you only want the 'value' part of that list so it can be `Vectorize()`-ed.

Second you construct a matrix using that function:

```
  mat <- outer( seq(.01, 10, length=100),  
                seq(.01, 10, length=100), 
                Vectorize( function(x,y) fourvar(a1=2, x/2, l1=2, l2=y/2) ) )
```

Then the task of creating the plot with labels in those positions can only be done easily with `lattice::contourplot`. After doing a reasonable amount of searching it does appear that the solution to geom_contour labeling is still a work in progress in ggplot2. The only labeling strategy I found is in an external package. However, the 'directlabels' package's function `directlabel` does not seem to have sufficient control to spread the labels out correctly in this case. In other examples that I have seen, it does spread the labels around the plot area. I suppose I could look at the code, but since it depends on the 'proto'-package, it will probably be weirdly encapsulated so I haven't looked.

```
require(reshape2)
mmat <- melt(mat)
str(mmat) # to see the names in the melted matrix
g <- ggplot(mmat, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, z=value) )
g <- g+stat_contour(aes(col = ..level..), breaks=seq(.1, .9, .1) )
g <- g + scale_colour_continuous(low = "#000000", high = "#000000") # make black
install.packages("directlabels", repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org", type="source")
require(directlabels)
direct.label(g)
```

Note that these are the index positions from the matrix rather than the ratios of parameters, but that should be pretty easy to fix.

[image]

This, on the other hand, is how easilyy one can construct it in lattice (and I think it looks "cleaner":

```
  require(lattice)
  contourplot(mat, at=seq(.1,.9,.1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As I think the question is still relevant, there have been some developments in the contour plot labeling in the `metR` package. Adding to the previous example will give you nice contour labeling also with `ggplot2`

```
require(metR)
g + geom_text_contour(rotate = TRUE, nudge_x = 3, nudge_y = 5)
```

[image: Labeled contour plot]