# indifference curves in R - plotting table with repeating function

Tags: r

I just spent last week learning R, and now I am playing with it, but I can't find the answer for this problem

I have utility function written like this

> u(x,y)=min(3x,9y)

and the goal is to plot a contour graph of this function.

I tried quite a lot of solutions, until now I came to this

```
  x<-seq(0,30,3)
  y<-seq(0,90,9)
  n<-1:11

  table<-c(
    pmin(x,y[1]),
    pmin(x,y[2]),
    pmin(x,y[3]),
    pmin(x,y[4]),
    pmin(x,y[5]),
    pmin(x,y[6]),
    pmin(x,y[7]),
    pmin(x,y[8]),
    pmin(x,y[9]),
    pmin(x,y[10]),
    pmin(x,y[11]))

mat<-matrix(table, ncol=11, nrow=11)
contour(x,y,mat)
```

and obviously, the contour graph is not very precise.

I would like to now, what can I use so I do not have to write the table by hand like this.

I wanted to use the sapply function somehow, but I have two values and I was kind of lost how to put them there.

and I would be very thankful, if someone showed me, how to plot this contour graph as most efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `outer` for this:

```
n <- 11
foo <- outer(X=seq_len(n), Y=seq_len(n), function(x, y) pmin(3*x, 9*y))
```

`outer` applies the specified function to all combinations of elements of the vectors passed to arguments `X` and `Y`. In this case, we're applying the function `pmin(3*x, 9*y)` to all pairs of elements of the two vectors, each of which are the numbers 1 to n.

```
foo

##       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
##  [1,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3     3
##  [2,]    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6     6     6
##  [3,]    9    9    9    9    9    9    9    9    9     9     9
##  [4,]    9   12   12   12   12   12   12   12   12    12    12
##  [5,]    9   15   15   15   15   15   15   15   15    15    15
##  [6,]    9   18   18   18   18   18   18   18   18    18    18
##  [7,]    9   18   21   21   21   21   21   21   21    21    21
##  [8,]    9   18   24   24   24   24   24   24   24    24    24
##  [9,]    9   18   27   27   27   27   27   27   27    27    27
## [10,]    9   18   27   30   30   30   30   30   30    30    30
## [11,]    9   18   27   33   33   33   33   33   33    33    33
```

```
contour(foo)
```

[image]

To increase the number of points at which the function is evaluated, just pass finer-resolution vectors:

```
foo2 <- outer(seq(1, 11, 0.01), seq(1, 11, 0.01), function(x, y) pmin(3*x, 9*y))
contour(foo2)
```

[image]

Now it is evaluated at 0.01 increments from 1 through 11.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for.
And is there any other way how to create the contour graph without making the matrix?
e.g. if I wrote sth like contour("exact mathematical function")

Comment: @johnnyheineken - not that I know of. I just saw [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19079152/489704) as well